# Can certain jellyfish photosynthesize in the medusa stage?

Tags: photosynthesis, marine-biology, invertebrates, symbiosis

Can jellyfish (at least some of them) do photosynthesis in the symbiosis with *zooxanthellae* in their medusa form as well? I've heard that only *Cassiopea andromeda* can but I wasn't able to find a credible source upholding such claim. (Wikipedia would be enough)

Comment: ''Can jellyfish photosynthesize when mature?'' 
or
''Can jellyfish (at least some of them) in their medusa do photosynthesis? ''
Which one is your primary question?

Comment: I'd like to know about the photosynthesis in the medusa form

Comment: Then please change the title accordingly. However I think it would get closed as an under researched [homework question](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq) . I did a simple google search and found numerous websites and a few books claiming that they cannot but their symbiont zooxanthallae can.Take a look at this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassiopea_andromeda#Alimentation_and_strategies).I learned something new, so thank you.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Of course, I did mean their symbiant

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh The title has no problems. It's common and acceptable to have a broader title with more specific details in the body of the question. Don't be so picky

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Zooxanthellae&oldid=736129723); Zooxanthellae are not bacteria but are dinoflagellates, a sort of protist. That means they are Eukaryotic.